# I want to restore memory in GDB when I debug core file

Tags: c++, c, linux, debugging, gdb

I want to restore memory in GDB when I debug core file.
I checked restore function in GDB when process is running. (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Dump_002fRestore-Files.html)
It was success.

But I want to restore memory when I debug core file.
I can use core_filter and I can select segment. but It is out very big size core file.
so I use a way that dump and restoring memory.

but it is possible when process is running.
I want to restore memory when process is not running. 
I need the way when I debug core dump file.

Can I restore memory in this way?

Do you know another ways?

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
Reading symbols from main...done.
[New LWP 19274]
Core was generated by `./main'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000040053a in main () at main.c:6
6       *a = 3;
(gdb) restore memory_dump binary &array 0 40
You can't do that without a process to debug.
```

Comment: But if there is no process running, there is no "memory"...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès When gdb loads a core file, it sets up virtual memory with the contents as of the time the core file was created, so variables and address contents can be examined. Though I'm not sure if that "memory" can be modified at all, since I've never had a reason to want such a thing.

Comment: @aschepler Right the core file is a capture of a memory, but why would you modify the picture if not running the corresponding process? I can understand one may modify the memory while debugging a running process but if not running what would this means?

Comment: @aschepler "it sets up virtual memory with the contents as of the time the core file was created, so variables and address contents can be examined." -- no, it does *not*.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I don't know how it's implemented, so "virtual memory" is likely inaccurate wording. I just meant it acts as though somehow loaded, so that commands using a variable or an address from the original process give that sort of view much like they would when attached to a program.

Comment: This appears to be an http://xyproblem.info What you are trying to *achieve*?

Comment: I don't change value of memory.  currently, core file is very big size. so in core_filter, I don\`t select file based shared memory.  the shared memory is saved to dump file. and then, I will restore the shared memory when I  debug core file. but... I think it is impossible.....

Comment: file based shared memory segment is very big size. but if I know some of the memory, I can debug core file.